# Reset formik form using mutations react query

Tags: reactjs, formik, react-query

I'm have a form that is using formik and react query. I want to reset the form on success.

Is there a way to pass resetForm function as a param to onSuccess ?

```
const mutation = useMutation(
  (newUser) =>
    axios.post(`/api/accounts`, newUser),
  {
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
      router.push(`/confirm-email?email=${data.email}`);
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      if (error.response && error.response.data.message) {
        openSnackbar(error.response.data.message);
      } else {
        openSnackbar('Something went wrong, please retry later');
      }
    },
  }
);
```

Form

```
<Formik
  onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
    mutation.mutate(values);
    setSubmitting(false);
  }}
>
  ...
</Formik>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have onSuccess on useMutation as well as in onMutate:

```
<Formik
  onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
    mutation.mutate(values, { onSuccess: ()=> resetForm() });
    setSubmitting(false);
  }}
>
  ...
</Formik>
```

Comment: can you please share the link of the documentation where this is mentioned. I feel so dumb I have look at the docs but wasn't able to find it

Comment: See: https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/mutations#mutation-side-effects